# uniform инициализация

Tags: c++, классы

```
class fraction {
public:
   int num;
   int dem;

};

int main() {
    fraction fr{1,2};
}
```

Как это работает? Я не предоставлял конструктор с параметрами `int` и по умолчанию они не предоставляются

```
fraction fr{1,2};
```

Прямая инициализация работает как и ожидается

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: В простых случаях класс и струстура (struct) это одно и то же. В Си (и в С++) всегда можно было инициализировать струтуру в порядке ее полей `fraction fr = {1, 2};`. Очевидно, что такое поведение унаследовалось и в новом синтаксисе объявления класса